# Класс с большим количеством полей

Tags: c++

Однажды у меня возникла проблема с тем, что мне нужно было в одном классе работать с большим количеством полей.

```
class MyClass
{
    
public:
    MyClass(Type field1, Type field2, ...);
    
    Type getField1();
    Type getField2();
    ...
    
private:
    Type m_field1;
    Type m_field2;
    ...
}
```

Конечно, как я понял, в том случае проблема была в плохом проектировании программы :)
Но всё таки, если понадобится сделать класс в котором будет достаточно много полей, то (лично мне) будет лень для каждого из них прописывать геттер, и писать всю эту колбасу в конструкторе. Нормальна ли тогда такая практика:

```
struct MyClassInfo
{
    Type field1;
    Type field2;
    ...
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(MyClassInfo info);
    
    const MyClassInfo & getMyClassInfo();
    
private:
    MyClassInfo m_info;
}
```

Comment: Ну, если вам понадобится только одно значение - вы все равно будете таскать сразу все. Да и инкапсуляции у вас никакой совсем...

Comment: @Harry, ну предполагалось, что эти поля и так должны быть доступны...

Comment: А зачем вам вообще методы доступа прописывать? Вы можете просто к полям напрямую обращаться.

Comment: Копирующий конструктор - это конечно хорошо. Тут вспомнилось - яицо или курица. Если нет никакого другого конструктора, кроме копирующего, кто даст первый экземпляр класса, для которого можно будет вызвать копирующий конструктор? Т.е. выйдет что класс есть, а создать обьект... а не с чего.

Comment: Если у вас много полей... не запрещено использовать va_args т.е. переменное число аргументов `f(...)`

Comment: Если у вас однотипные конструкции, вы можете кусок кода завернуть в define, и дублировать, например `#define fld_def(a) private: Type a; public: Type get##a(){ return a;}` что-то такое и заюзать так `fld_def(field1); fld_def(field2);`

Comment: Массивы для слабых?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Может имеется ввиду что типы разные. Может хотят названия человеко-понятные.

Comment: @nick_n_a, мне не нужно чтобы кто-то мог изменять эти поля.

Comment: @nick_n_a, у меня нет там конструктора копирования...

Comment: @nick_n_a, идея с дефайном очень прикольная, но здесь есть одно но: если я захочу назвать поле именем, допустим, m_damage, то соответствующий ей геттер будет с именем... getm_damage(). Выглядит странно

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, опять же да, поля носят разную смысловую нагрузку, и пихать их все в один массив по моему ещё хуже чем то, что я написал...

Comment: define позволяет обьявить сокращения и делать свёртки кода используя правило. Если вам  getm_damage не нравится - можно сделать другое правило. Апкейсить одну букву - боюсь не выйдет. Для даного случая... считаю лучше одно правило для всех. То путаница будет. Возможно лучше для метода добавлять гет, а для поля добавлять спереди m_  - такое правило тоже легко составить. `#define fld_def(a)  тип get##a() .... тип m_##a;` вроде такого